# How to test null Double value in Jasper Reports?

Tags: jasper-reports

I need to show a static text field only if the price value is not null, i tried to do this:

```
<printWhenExpression>
  <![CDATA[$F{price} != null]]>
</printWhenExpression>
```

But this not works, it's always returns true with Double value, in a String value it worked.

Edit: The code started to works, I will keep this because the helpfull reply.

Comment: Are you still having issues with this?

Comment: No, thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

This is **not** true if the `$F{price}` is `null` the expression will return `false`.

Maybe you do not need to check for that is `null` but that it is not `Double.NaN`

```
<printWhenExpression>
   <![CDATA[new Boolean($F{price} != null && !$F{price}.isNaN())]]>
</printWhenExpression>
```

I suggest you output the value of `$F{price}`, to understand what it is...

**NOTE**: I'm using new Boolean() for compatibility reasons (jasper report v 3) this is not needed in jasper report v 5,6

Comment: I don't know why, but my code starts to work correctly, thanks anyway.